# Is the set of all matrices of rank less-or-equal to a given number closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

Is the set $\{A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}: \mathrm{rank}(A) \le k\}$ closed? ($k \le \min \{m,n\}$). I think it is closed, but I have no idea about how to prove it. Can someone provide me a rigorous proof or provide me some useful links?

Answer (score 4):

It is closed, being defined by a finite number of polynomial equations, namely those giving the vanishing of all the minors of order $k+1$.